# Netbsd, what is dk?

Tags: netbsd

Simple question, today making iostat on netbsd machine I see..

```
    iostat 2 3
          tty              ld0               ld1               dk0               dk1               dk2               dk3               dk4               cd0             CPU
     tin  tout  KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s  us ni sy in id
```

---explanation---

```
ld0 is the first virtio hd
ld1 is the second virtio hd
cd0 is the first SATA cdrom
```

what is dk1-4?

Comment: I believe that's disk 1 - 4

Comment: nope, is refer to gpt partitions, disk are ld0 ld1 or sd0 sd1, or wd0 wd1..

Comment: As in `D`is`K` partitions.  `dk` is short for that.

Comment: BSD treats GPT partitions as Disks.  This is only only a semantics difference.  MBR/DOS style disks are limited to 4 Partitions.  See [this post](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/blogs/steven-torrence1/2020/04/25/a-difference-between-basic-and-bsd-layout-schemes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found..gpt.
I usually use "disklabel" to create bsd slice, but this create
MBR partition.
To create gpt partition on disk (really simple..1G on virtio disk)

```
gpt destroy ld1||echo "Not gpt!"
gpt create ld1
gpt add -a 2m -l TRY -t ffs -s 1G ld1
```

Iostat confirm operation ok (a new dk appear, dk5)

```
      tty              ld0               ld1               dk0               dk1               dk2               dk3               dk4               cd0               dk5             CPU
 tin  tout  KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s   KB/t  t/s  MB/s  us ni sy in id
   1    42 15.59    2 0.036  44.95    0 0.018  2.000    1 0.000  13.82    1 0.010  1.571    0 0.000  13.99    1 0.012  19.90    1 0.015  4.000    0 0.000  0.000    0 0.000   0  0  0  0 100
```

Comment: You really should try `bsdlablel` - [Manpage](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdlabel&sektion=8&format=html), if you're going to use GPT partitioned disks

Comment: is netbsd, no bsdlabel command

Comment: Granted, my mistake, but see [this mailing list archive](https://muc.lists.netbsd.users.narkive.com/lLfz2pQa/gpt-vs-bsd-label).